# Windows Phone Unit Tests don't work with VS 2013

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I have different WP8 projects with some unit tests. As long as I run the tests in visual studio 2012 on my work computer everything is fine. But when I open the solution on my notebook who don't have the 2012 installed, but only the 2013 I always get the following error message when I run the tests:

> Deployment for project xysucceeded. Time taken: 19 sec Specified
>   argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name:
>   localeId

I already tried it with installing the WP8 along to visual studio 2013 (although Visual Studio 2013 has the sdk integrated). Also I created a new Testprojekt with an easy Assert.IsTrue(true) test. But it also end up in the same error.

Did anyone had this problem as well?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well my tests are working again. What I changed is I deleted the bridge between two network adapters. Because of that the emulator had to reconfigure the internet access. After that everything worked again.